# Conflict between esvect and unicode-math?

Tags: unicode-math

I have a problem with esvect and unicode-math.
Here is a MWE (of course, I don't need esvect in this example):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{STIX two Text}
\setmathfont{STIX two Math}
\usepackage{esvect}


\begin{document}
    $x+y$
\end{document}
```

I edited my first message with a shorter MWE.

I get this warning message:
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `U/esvect/m/n' in size <5.5> not available
(Font)              size <5> substituted on input line 10.

[1

{C:/Users/didie/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/fonts/map/pdftex/pdftex.map}]
(./probleme_esvect.aux)

LaTeX Font Warning: Size substitutions with differences
(Font)              up to 0.5pt have occurred.

I don't get it because I don't use esvec in this example. And I don't know if I provide with enough information but I don't know which part of the log file would be relevant.

I chekced in C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\fonts\tfm\public\esvect and I have:
vect5.tfm, vect6.tfm, vect7.tfm, vect8.tfm and vect10.tfm

Comment: compile a small document `\documentclass[]{article}\usepackage{esvect}\begin{document}$\vv{AB}$\footnote{Michel Rolle: $1652$--$1719$}\end{document}` with *pdflatex*. This should create the needed tfm files. (you will perhaps to repeat that if other size are missing too).

Comment: Thank you. I dit what you wrote and I don't get the error message anymore. But I still have the warning message: LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `U/esvect/m/n' in size <5.5> not available

Comment: ignore that, it is normal, the fd-file declares discrete size.

Comment: You seem to have a faulty TeX distribution, because `vect8.tfm` is included in the distribution of `esvect`.

Comment: @egreg. Should I uninstall the package esvect and reinstall it?

Comment: @Didier You can try. What OS are you running? And what TeX distribution?

Comment: Windows 11 and Miktex. I wonder if the problem doesn’t come from fourier-otf. When back home, I will try to comment that line

Comment: Are you sure you need the `esvect` with Unicode fonts? Extensible arrows are usually included (commands `\overrightarrow`, etc.): as your example uses `fourier-otf`, have a look at the documentation `Erewhon-Math.pdf` which shows examples on page 8.

Comment: Yes Daniel. I’ve just seen that. Maybe I don’t need esvect

Comment: @egreg There is really a problem with esvect and some fonts. If don't specifiy any fonts, it runs ok. But if I specify Erewhon or Stix two, I have this warning message. I Think I will find an alternative to the esvect package

Comment: @Didier The warning (as opposed to the missing font error that should be solved by reinstalling and rebuilding the font mappings) is essentially innocuous: you just get a slightly different font size. Can you please supplement the code so that the warning appears?

Comment: @ egreg. I’ll try that tomorrow morning (I live in France). How do I rebuild the font mappings? I uninstalled esvect and reinstalled it, but it didn’t change anything. The esvect package is « pretty old » (10 years from the last update) Isn’t there anything newer. Daniel Flipo told me to use \overrightarrow because I use Erewhon, and he is right: with this font, the arrows are nicer. But, if one day I decide to change (STIX Two, for example), \overrightarrow will give me ugly arrows. One last thing : I could ignore the warnings, but I hate having warning messages after compilation

Comment: @egreg. I edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your code

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}
\usepackage{esvect}

\begin{document}

$x+y+\vv{x+y}+\overrightarrow{x+y}$

\end{document}
```

where I added examples of overarrows, respectively `esvect` and STIX Two Math, I get

[image]

You decide what kind of arrows you prefer. But there's also the warning

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `U/esvect/m/n' in size <5.5> not available
(Font)              size <5> substituted on input line 11.
```

which is a bit annoying. It stems from the fact that in the olden times when Type1 fonts were not available, fonts were offered at fixed sizes in order not to fill disk space with useless copies of bitmap fonts.

If you look in `uesvect.fd` (the font description file) you see

```
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{esvect}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{esvect}{m}{n}{%
      <5><6><7><8><9><10>gen*vect%
      <10.95><12><14.4><17.28><20.74><24.88>vect10%
      }{}
```

You can easily fix this description to allow for fonts at any size.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}
\usepackage{esvect}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{esvect}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{esvect}{m}{n}{
  <-5.5> vect5
  <5.5-6.5> vect6
  <6.5-7.5> vect7
  <7.5-8.5> vect8
  <8.5-9.5> vect9
  <9.5-> vect10
}{}


\begin{document}

$x+y+\vv{x+y}+\overrightarrow{x+y}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works perfectly fine